# How to use search button with jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am developing a website where i am using search bar using jquery ui autocomplete plugin.

But now that only works with keyboard Enter and mouse click after selecting from dropdown. I have also put a search button,but dropdown closes when clicked on button and no redirection or anything happens.

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
        source: url + 'Home/searchallresults_shop',
        autoFocus:true,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#searchallresults_shop" ).val( ui.item.name );
            console.log(ui);
            window.location.href = ui.item.url;
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text"  name="searchbox" id="searchbox">
<button type="submit" id="searchbutton_jq">Search</button>
```

How can i make search button select first autocomplete item and redirect?

Thanks.

Comment: Your autocomplete is not bound to any of the HTML elements you provided. There is no element with the id `searchbox_shop`

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt sorry,my bad.Now question edited

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly what you're saying. I think what you mean is that when a result item has focus, you want that to populate a field so the user can then click the 'Search' button instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or clicking on the result. I'm just not sure how often this will come into play.

Consider the following code:

```js
var myData = [{
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    url: "https://jquery.com/"
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    url: "https://jqueryui.com/"
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    url: "https://sizzlejs.com/"
  }
];
$(function() {
  function redirect(u) {
    window.location.href = u;
  }
  $("#searchbox").autocomplete({
    source: myData,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function(e, ui) {
      $("#searchallresults_shop").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#searchbutton_jq").data("url", ui.item.url);
      return false;
    },
    focus: function(e, ui) {
      $("#searchallresults_shop").val(ui.item.label);
      $("#searchbutton_jq").data("url", ui.item.url);
      return false;
    }
  });
  $("#searchbutton_jq").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data("url") != undefined) {
      redirect($(this).data("url"));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="searchbox" id="searchbox" />
<button type="submit" id="searchbutton_jq"> Search
  </button>
<br /> Shop: <input type="text" id="searchallresults_shop" />
```

If one of the items has `focus`, we can use the callback to perform some actions. If focus is sustained and the user clicks 'Search', the expected redirects happens. The same if they select an item. Remember that `blur` may also trigger `select`. Clicking on the button would trigger a `blur` event, so it's not clear which is really bubbling to the top since they both do the same thing.